# JCheckBox checks for values in JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I am a beginner at Java GUIs.

I have a **JTable** with a few columns and one of those columns has values for some rows and for some other rows there are no values.

I would like to make a JCheckBox listener see if there are values inside that column of the JTable, and if the box is selected to resort the table showing those values. If I uncheck the box, I want the table to be shown with the no values in that column. How could the above be done?
Thank you.
Here is my code. I also have some two JComboBox that do what I want them to do.

```
public class myGui extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

JPanel pane = new JPanel();
JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();    
AccomodationList list;
String[] roomOrCabin = {"Room","Cabin"};
String[] booked = {"Booked","Not Booked","All"};
JComboBox dropRoom = new JComboBox(roomOrCabin); 
JComboBox dropBook = new JComboBox(booked);
JCheckBox ownerButton = new JCheckBox("Owner",true);
JTable table;
DefaultTableModel model;
Vector<String> columnNames;
TableRowSorter<TableModel> trs;

public myGui(AccomodationList list){

    super(new BorderLayout());
    pane.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

    columnNames = new Vector<String>();             

    columnNames.addElement("Accomodation Number");
    columnNames.addElement("Number of Beds");
    columnNames.addElement("Number of Rooms");
    columnNames.addElement("Type");
    columnNames.addElement("Cost per Night");
    columnNames.addElement("Owner");
    columnNames.addElement("Booked");
    columnNames.addElement("Client");
    columnNames.addElement("Booked Statistics");        

    Vector<Vector> f = populateTable(list);

    table = new JTable(f, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    model = new DefaultTableModel(f,columnNames){
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
          Class returnValue;
          if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
            returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
          } else {
            returnValue = Object.class;
          }
          return returnValue;
        }
    };
    trs = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);


    table.setRowSorter(trs);

    this.list = list;
    pane.add(table);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
    pane.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    pane2.add(dropRoom);
    pane2.add(dropBook);
    pane2.add(ownerButton);
    pane.add(pane2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(pane);
    dropRoom.addActionListener(this);
    dropBook.addActionListener(this);
    ownerButton.addActionListener(this);

}

public Vector<Vector> populateTable(AccomodationList list){

    Vector<Vector> f = new Vector<Vector>();

    String t;

    for(Accomodation a: list.getList()){
        Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>();
        t=String.valueOf(a.getNoAcc());
        v.addElement(a.getNoAcc()); 
        t=String.valueOf(a.getSumOfBeds());
        v.addElement(t);    
        t=String.valueOf(a.getNoBedrooms());
        v.addElement(t);    
        t=String.valueOf(a.getType());
        v.addElement(t);
        t=String.valueOf(a.getCost());
        v.addElement(t);
        t=String.valueOf(a.getInitials(a.getOwner()));
        v.addElement(t);
        t=String.valueOf(a.getBooked().toString());
        v.addElement(t);
        t=String.valueOf(a.getInitials(a.getClient()));
        v.addElement(t);
        t=String.valueOf(a.getBookedCnt());
        v.addElement(t);

        f.addElement(v);
    }
    return f;

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == dropRoom){
                String text = dropRoom.getSelectedItem().toString();
                System.out.println("text: "+text);
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                  trs.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                  try {
                    trs.setRowFilter(
                        RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
                  } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
                    System.err.println("Bad regex pattern");
                  }
                }                                  
    }

    if(e.getSource() == dropBook){
                String selected = dropBook.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String text="";
                if ("Booked".equals(selected)){text = "true";}else if("Not Booked".equals(selected)){text = "false";}else{text = "";}
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                  trs.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    try {
                      trs.setRowFilter(
                          RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
                    } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
                      System.err.println("Bad regex pattern");
                    }
                } 

    }
    if(e.getSource() == ownerButton){
        JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
        if (cb.isSelected()) {

                System.out.println("Owner is enabled");

        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Owner is disabled");


        }

    }
}


}
```

Each row can have or not have a `String` value for the column Owner. I want to sort the table on those two facts using the JCheckBox.

Comment: Post us what you have tried so far...

Comment: I'm confused. where is this checkbox? Is this outside of the table, or embedded in a row?

Comment: It's outside the table.

Comment: and the function of this checkbox is to filter the rows?

Comment: Yes. That is my intention

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to add a listener to your checkbox like so :

```
checkbox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {


        }else {


        }
    }
});
```

Now the question is what do you want to do when you select the checkbox. You want some kind of sorting algorithm in your table model. There is a good example at this website :

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SampleSortingTableModel.htm

You just need to add some kind of **Comparable** to your entity objects which are represented in the table model. By default empty values will be shown at the bottom anyway.

Comment: Let me edit my question with the code. I'm sorry if I was so vague.